# Loud Clicking/Groaning sound when braking at low speed

Tags: brakes, hyundai, noise, accent

So recently my brake( rear driver side) has been making a really loud Clicking/Groaning sound, sorry that is the best I can explain the sound.

It happens after driving for a while and the sound appears when I apply a certain amount of pressure on the brakes if I apply a little or a lot it doesn't make the noise. Also like I said in the title it makes the sound only when the car is below 20kmh or so.

I just wanted to see if this was a easy fix before I go to get it checked and throw away more money.

Oh and my cars a 2013 hyundai accent with ~58000km

**EDIT:** Oh i noticed that the applying pressure part might be confusing what i mean is, If i step really hard on the pedal it won't make it and if it is just lightly it also won't make it, but at a normal braking speed it is really loud

Comment: Oh i noticed that the applying perssure part might be confusing what i mean is, If i step really hard on the pedal it won't make it and if it is just lightly it also won't make it, but at a normal braking speed it is really loud

Answer (score 1):

Given the age of the question I am sure it has been resolved by now. But it sounds like a badly worn brake rotor and pads. It's not unusual for brake noises to be especially noisy when just the right amount of pressure is applied to the pedal, not too much, not too little. Once you unbolt a wheel from your car the disc brake assembly is right there in view, and it is usually pretty easy to spot if something really bad is going on.